# Recursive Formula (Sequences)

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursive-algorithms

The Question is give the recursive formula of each question, and add another 2 terms.
1. 8,14,26,50,...
2. 2,6,-18,-54,...
3. 6,7,7.5,7.75,...
4. 3,10,24,52,...

The problem is that I can't understand the interval in each term for example 8 and 14, the interval is 6 then 14 and 26 is 12, then 24 for 26 and 50. I know that the intervals increases by doubling the last interval. 6*2=12, 12*2=24 and so forth. But I don't know how to get the recursive formula.

Comment: In the first one, try multiplying each term by 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_n$ denotes $n^{\text{th}}$ term of sequence.

You got - 
\begin{align}
&a_2-a_1=6 \times 2^0\\
&a_3-a_2=6 \times 2^1\\
&a_4-a_3=6\times 2^2\\
\end{align}

I hope you see the pattern now

> $$a_{n+1}-a_n=6\cdot 2^{n-1}\implies \boxed{\color{blue}{a_{n+1}=a_n+6\cdot 2^{n-1}}}$$

You can proceed similarly in the other two sequences.

Comment: In the second question what is the pattern. I don't get it in the interval of 6 and -18 which is -24.

Comment: Also the last question I don't quite get it. What is the pattern???

Comment: I only got the first question right and the others I can't understand it quite enough to solve them

Comment: @ClarenceFeliciano For third one : the difference is getting half every time, starting from 1. That is $$a_{n+1}-a_{n}=2^{-(n-1)}$$

Comment: @ClarenceFeliciano For fourth one the difference is doubling after each term starting from 7. Thus you can with out for it in the exact same manner as the first one, the only thing which would change is, 6 is replaced by 7.

Comment: @ClarenceFeliciano For the second one, I too am not able to get the pattern. I think there is either a typo, or few more terms must be given.